# removeFromSuperview is not working if it is called from another class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have one main view as shown in picture. I add 2 subviews into that and each has their own view controller.

In `ipadMainViewController`,

```
self.dTVC= [[dialoguesTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"dialoguesTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.dTVC.view setFrame:rectFordTVC];
[self.view addSubview:self.dTVC.view];
```

After that, I want to remove the view of `dialoguesTableViewController` if I press a button in `CategoriesViewController`. But, I can't remove it. 
In `CategoriesViewController`, I write like this but `dialoguesTableViewController` can't be removed from `ipadMainViewController`. How shall I do this?

In `CategoriesViewController`, I write code like this but it is not working.

```
self.dTVC= [[dialoguesTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"dialoguesTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.dTVC.view removeFromSuperview];
```

[image]

Comment: use NSNotificationCenter or create delegate for that class

Comment: `self.dTVC` does not make from another class. I hope, you need to go through the `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: OR just use the messaging protocol(method) to remove the View from another class .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are few ways how to do it:

**First way:**

Add observer to ipadMainViewController initialization method or viewDidLoad method it depends on your needs.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(buttonPressed)
                                             name:@"kNotificationDidPressedButon"
                                           object:nil];
```

Add `-buttonPressed` method to ipadMainViewController controller for removing your view or other your purposes.

```
- (void)buttonPressed
{
   // remove view here
}
```

in the CategoriesViewController in the method where you tap on the appropriate button add this code:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kNotificationDidPressedButon"
                                                   object:self];
```

**Second way:**

Add delegate property to CategoriesViewController. you can find info how to make delegate for example here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

**Third way:**

Use objective-c blocks

**Initial advice as for beginner:**

I suggest you to start from first way, because it is most simplest for understanding. Also you have to remove observer in ipadMainViewControllerr in `-dealloc` or `-viewWillDisapper` method, it depends of where you have add observer e.g. in `-init` method or in `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear` callback;

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`

Comment: Thanks. I use delegate now. :)

Comment: ok, this more professional way as I think. But it depends on the task, but in your case I suggest you to use delegate or block. it's up to you, just be sure that the delegate object is respond to selector

Answer (score 0):

try this....

add below code where you can remove view

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) name:@"REMOVE" object:nil];
}
-(void)removeFromSuperviev{

     [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

add below code form you need to remove

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"REMOVE" object:nil];
```